# Xpages - Return correct documents using getDocumentByKey(unid, true)

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, ssjs

I have a list, but I only want to narrow down my list to only documents with the current unid which appears on the browser, I did this by calling on the getDocumentByKey method of the viewEv object and pass in the unid arguement.

Strangly, this worked for only the newest document. The other documents, just shows all the list not belonging to the unid on the browser.

Any help will be appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
  function getCalObj(){ 
    var viewEv:NotesView = database.getView("Diary");
    viewEv.setAutoUpdate(false);    
    var docEv:NotesDocument = viewEv.getFirstDocument();
    var doc:NotesDocument = diaryDoc.getDocument();
    var sUNID = doc.getUniversalID();
    print("unid: " + sUNID);
    docEv = viewEv.getDocumentByKey(sUNID, true);

    while (docEv != null) {
      ........
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use get**All**DocumentsByKey() to get **all** documents with this sUNID?

Comment: Yes, that was missed.

I've made the below modification and its now working.

Thanks.

var dcEv:NotesDocumentCollection = viewEv.getAllDocumentsByKey(sUNID);
 
if(dcEv.getCount() == 0){
 print("data not available...")
}

var docEv:NotesDocument = dcEv.getFirstDocument();

while (docEv != null) {
    ........
}

Comment: Good, I put this in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use get**All**DocumentsByKey() to get **all** documents with this sUNID.

```
var dcEv:NotesDocumentCollection = viewEv.getAllDocumentsByKey(sUNID);
if (dcEv.getCount() > 0) { 
    var docEv:NotesDocument = dcEv.getFirstDocument(); 
    while (docEv != null) { 
         ........ 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Krut.